# Android how to change gridview highlight color?

Tags: android, gridview, colors, highlight

how can change the highlight color of a imageView inside gridview.

I've tried this,

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width, height));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_beh);
     //   imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    String s=(String)HiveApp.mgd[position].posters[2].image.url;
 //   imageView.setImageDrawable(getPicture(items[position]));
   HiveApp.id.download(s, imageView); 


  //     id.DisplayImage(s, imageView);

    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I resolve it my self, you shoud add this to your layout xml

```
 android:listSelector="@drawable/panel_picture_frame_background"
```

and not this

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gridview_highlight_selector);
```

thanks

Comment: Worked for me too. Option above crashed.

Answer (score 3):

Add an `imageview_highlight_selector.xml` file containing the following content to the `drawable` folder, and then call `imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gridview_highlight_selector);`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/highlight_bg" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_bg" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

I would suggest you define your gridview item in an xml file, and then inflate that xml from inside your Java code, which would be neater.

**EDIT:**

If you only want to use color rather a drawable, you can add a `color` subfolder to the `res` folder, and add the following content as `gridview_highlight_selector.xml` to the `color` folder, and call `imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gridview_highlight_selector);` in your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffff" />
    <item android:color="#ff3697de" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this change the state of the background of the item, and the orange highlight don't disappear...