# How to highlight a Bitmap? Like Google Play

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, highlight

**How to highlight a Bitmap?** Like Google play.

[image][image]

My images are in a server, so I´d like to **not** download two images to make this effect.

**What I have tried:**

I just try to use Layers but it don't make a transparent highlight effect. 
The Bitmap is set on an `Imagebutton`.

Maybe canvas should work, creating a drawable transparent with a light color, I tried some codes but doesn't work or its because I don't know how to handle this.

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

                    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
                    layers[0] = bitmapDrawable;
                    layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.default_button_pressed);
                    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

**default_button_pressed**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <gradient android:endColor="#FFFFFF" android:startColor="#ccffff" android:angle="90" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#33364252" />

</shape>
```

Comment: I would suggest posting your code that uses layers, and change your question to ask for help with the specific issue you are encountering.

Comment: Can you provide us an example of highlighted and usual bitmap? It will be easier to understand what you want.

Comment: I just update with the example from Google play and what I have tried.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I don't think this is actually highlighting a bitmap, but having an image being loaded in a GridView and applying styles to it when an item is selected. It will "highlight" it by default if you do that

Comment: @MarcosPlacona If I do what you said, it won´t highlight inside the bitmap, only the border of it, as you can see in APIDemos.

Comment: @Marckaraujo pretty sure you can create a selector for it, and apply a background highlight to it. Like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635893/android-how-to-change-gridview-highlight-color

Comment: @MarcosPlacona, I tried, don't work, using a selector the highlight effect just cover outside of bitmap if the ImageButton is bigger then the bitmap, it won't apply the effect to bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to do with an `OnTouchListener` and the using the `setColourFilter` method of `ImageButton`

```
  ImageButton aButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MY_IMAGEBUTTON_ID);
   aButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
            ImageButton button = (ImageButton)v;
            if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                button.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);
                return true;
            } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                button.setColorFilter(null);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: It works man, but not with this color, I used the colorcode from @vmironov.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `ColorFilter`:

```
Imagebutton.setColorFilter(0x808fd2ea);
```